# VBA list arguments by their name from largest to lowest

Tags: excel, vba, list, max

I am trying to evaluate the values of different arguments and get the sorted list from largest to lowest, BUT displayed as argument names. What I have so far is a simple MAX function that returns the largest value.

```
Result = Application.Max(Chicago_SantaFe, Vancouver_SantaFe, Calgary_SaltLakeCity)

Result_Label.caption = Result
```

As you can see my arguments in MAX function are "Chicago_SantaFe, Vancouver_SantaFe, Calgary_SaltLakeCity"
So the result would be something like:

Chicago_SantaFe
Vancouver_SantaFe
Calgary_SaltLakeCity

Could someone, please, answer this question?

Comment: Nothing is clear in your question, I am afraid... What does "arguments" mean in your question/code context? An argument should have a meaning only in case of a `Function` or  `Sub` arguments. What do you want them to be? Are them arguments of this type? If yes, please post all the context. Otherwise, we cannot (me, at least) understand what you want.

Comment: Just edited OP, mate. My arguments are the things written in Max( ), this function gives the number that's the largest, but I need the name of the argument, not it's value

Comment: `Max` function does not care about the origin of the values to evaluate. In order to obtain what you want, even if I do not understand why, you should clarify **why you want that**, you have to proceed in a different way. If you will explain all the context, you will maybe receive an answer to solve the real problem, not the one you try exposing.  One way would be to  place so named 'arguments' name in an array (as strings), and their value in another one, but in the same order. Finally you can match the value array order with the string array. This will be only a way, but not the single one.

Comment: Yes, and I couldn't find teh right syntax for what I need

Comment: If **what you need** is only in hour head, nobody can help you, I'm afraid...

Comment: I literally explained what I am looking for. My code returns the largest value of the written array of arguments, but what I need is a sorted list that lists the argument names not their value, nor even multiple values. I need the NAME of the argument that has the largest value, at least, as a first step, before can try to figure out how to arrange all of the arguments in sorted manner from largest to lowest

Comment: Largest to smallest based on population? number of letters in each name? Geographical area? largest latitude vales?

Comment: No, each argument has a numeric value that is modified in different circumstances as the code runs. That is what my MAX function does, it returns that number of the argument that has the largest one. But instead of that number which is the largest, I need the name of that argument, and preferably a whole list of arguments from largest to lowest by their individual values

Comment: I don't understand how to use it, could you elaborate?

Comment: Finally understand what you are doing. (And I guess, from the comments above, I'm not the only one that was confused). Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to have a map between your variable and your variable name.
Then sort by values and output the names.

Here is one method that assumes there are no duplicates (two variables that have the same value).  If that is not the case, the code can be modified easily enough.

Since you do not show how you assign the values to your variables, I just did that directly, but you can substitute your method.

```
Option Explicit
Sub due()
    Const Chicago_SantaFe As Long = 1
    Const Vancouver_SantaFe As Long = 7
    Const Calgary_SaltLakeCity As Long = 3
    Dim v As Variant, w As Variant, s As String
    
Dim myDict As Object
Dim AL As Object
Set myDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

myDict.Add Key:=Chicago_SantaFe, Item:="Chicago_SantaFe"
myDict.Add Key:=Vancouver_SantaFe, Item:="Vancouver_SantaFe"
myDict.Add Key:=Calgary_SaltLakeCity, Item:="Calgary_SaltLakeCity"

'Use arraylist for sorting
Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For Each v In myDict.keys
    AL.Add v
Next v

AL.Sort
AL.Reverse

For Each v In AL
    s = s & vbLf & myDict(v)
Next v

MsgBox Mid(s, 2)

End Sub
```

[image]

If there might be duplicate values for your variables, and to use a routine where there are more variables, you can use something like the below, where you

- make two arrays

  - one of the variable values
  - another of the variable names
- loop through both arrays to create the mapping
- instead of storing just the variable name as the item, store a collection of the variable names associated with a particular value

Then, for output, you

- sort the keys
- loop through the collection stored with each key

```
Option Explicit
Sub due()
    Const Chicago_SantaFe As Long = 1
    Const Vancouver_SantaFe As Long = 7
    Const Calgary_SaltLakeCity As Long = 3
    Const Nome_Fairbanks As Long = 3
    Dim v As Variant, w As Variant, s As String, col As Collection
    Dim I As Long
    
v = Array(Chicago_SantaFe, Vancouver_SantaFe, Calgary_SaltLakeCity, Nome_Fairbanks)
w = Array("Chicago_SantaFe", "Vancouver_SantaFe", "Calgary_SaltLakeCity", "Nome_Fairbanks")
    
Dim myDict As Object
Dim AL As Object
Set myDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For I = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
    If Not myDict.exists(v(I)) Then
        Set col = New Collection
        col.Add w(I)
        myDict.Add Key:=v(I), Item:=col
    Else
        myDict(v(I)).Add w(I)
    End If
Next I

'Use arraylist for sorting
Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For Each v In myDict.keys
    AL.Add v
Next v

AL.Sort
AL.Reverse

For Each v In AL
    For Each w In myDict(v)
        s = s & vbLf & w
    Next w
Next v

MsgBox Mid(s, 2)

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a thing I was trying to make. But could you explain how does entities in vcorrespond to entities in w? How do I know that the right ones are connected, because in w I intend to concatinate it with the actual value like "Nome_Fairbanks" & Nome_Fairbanks & "%" to show me the name of the arguments and it's numeric value. I just need to understand how the v and w entities are connected? Is it just the order in which they are written in those arrays?

Comment: @Eduards They correspond in order because that is how they were set up.  You never show how you assign values to your variables, but you can do that in many ways. *"in w I intend to concatinate it with the actual value "*. Why would you do it that way?  Just concatenate the dictionary key with dictionary item (or collection items if you are using that method).

Comment: Already wrote the code for that, but still, I assume that V and w entries correlate by the order in array, is that right?

Comment: @Eduards Yes. As I wrote above, that is how I set them up.

Comment: Yeah and it seems to work so thanks, friend! I am just wondering how does the macro know that Chicago_SantaFe in v corresponds to "Chicago_SantaFe" in w

Comment: @Eduards  I don't know how to answer any more clearly. And you've already restated it: *"correlate by the order in array"*. So the first element in each array represents one pair; the 2nd element represents the second pair; the third element in each array represents the third pair, etc.  Perhaps reading more about VBA arrays (do an internet search) would be helpful in your understanding.